# How to change CheckBox.Checked in VB.NET based on "yes"/"no" column

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview, string-comparison

I have a form with a `DataGridView` and `CheckBox`. What I want is when `DataGridView` index changes it should change `CheckBox` checked state, or if I press arrow down or up `CheckBox` should change depending on cell value. Here is my code:

```
Public Sub cellclick()
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    Dim r As Integer = usergrid.CurrentRow.Index
    row = Me.usergrid.Rows(r)
   'the value of the cell("ACCES1") maybe yes or no
    If row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString = "YES" Then
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked
        'i also try checkbox1.checked=true
    ElseIf row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString = "NO" Then
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked
        'i also try checkbox1.checked=false
    End If
End Sub 

Private Sub usergrid_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles usergrid.CellEnter
    cellclick()
End Sub
```

UPATE:

I change my if else code to this following lines of code but still not working heres my new code:

```
    If row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value = "YES" Then
        CheckBox1.Checked = True
        MsgBox(row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value) 'this is working and it echoes me the cell content everytime i click or change the grid index. it message me to "YES" and sometimes "NO" depends upon on the cell content/value
    Else
        CheckBox1.Checked = False
        MsgBox(row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value) 'this is working and it echoes me the cell content everytime i click or change the grid index
    End If
```

Comment: the possible value of `access1` is `'yes' or 'no'`

Comment: Debug your code. Put breakpoint inside a `cellclick` function. It seems like your function wasn't called, `CellEnter` event doesn't fired

Comment: Theres a difference between `CellEnter` and the current row changing index. Which one is it? Also what arrow down and up are you talking about?

Comment: You can look at: RowEnter or RowLeave event as this would fire the index change... From there do what you need.

Comment: @436f6465786572 `cellenter` maybe, but it works in both `cellcontentclick  and cellenter event` only the line of msgbox (question updated). i mean it is pressing arrow up and down in keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting the current row. since your function is not focusing on it. so make the following changes in the method as well as call:

```
Private Sub usergrid_CellEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles usergrid.CellEnter
    cellclick(e)
End Sub
Public Sub cellclick(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)
    Dim row As DataGridViewRow
    row = Me.usergrid.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    If row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString = "YES" Then
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked         
    ElseIf row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString = "NO" Then
        CheckBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked          
    End If
 End Sub
```

Comment: your suggestion is still not working.. i don't know what is wrong with my code and yours.. but it is really not working

Comment: put break point and check value of `row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString`

Comment: i did. `row.Cells("ACCESS1").Value.ToString` gives me the correct value from the `datagridview` only the problem is the `checkbox1` it doesn't change when `cellclick(e)` is called.. it actually turns me in `msgbox` the value of the cell